# How to leverage Webpack DLLs across multiple React apps?

Tags: dll, reactjs, webpack

We use React across multiple micro-services that render HTML fragments in a bigger legacy web app.

As of right now, each React app is importing a React DLL which we created using webpack.DllPlugin and loaded in the app webpack module via webpack.DllReferencePlugin. Even though it's leveraging the browser cache, it is still doing a round trip to the server.

My issue is not limited to the React module. This is just for the purpose of illustrating what I'm trying to do. We have built multiple DLLs to share code across micro-apps.

How would you go to have the first React app to be instantiated to load the React DLL and make it available globally?

I've written some inline script that injects script tags in the head but it feels like this isn't the right way. I'm wondering if there is a webpack way to achieve that.

Is there a way to have the app load the DLL asynchronously if needed and make it available to the rest of the apps on the current page?